# Get one value when cell input is same

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to get one value instead of all values when they have the same name. 
within an sql query. Im using fullcalendar. and have two tables one for the `events(evenement)` and one for the `receiver(evenementontvanger)`.

**`evenementontvanger`**:

```
id   idEvent   
1     231       
2     231       
3     231
```

**`evenement`**:

```
id   title   
231   hello
```

I would like to show only one title not 3 
my sql query:

```
"SELECT 
    *
FROM
    `evenement`
        JOIN
    `evenementontvanger` ON `evenementontvanger`.`idEvent` = `evenement`.`id`
WHERE
    `idEvent` = `evenement`.`id`"
```

Comment: yes u can but showing one will show only one of idWerknemer. So how u want to manage that ?

Comment: I know it will;) i already managed that but for the admin i would like to view all the events. but only one time not for each idWerknemer;)

Comment: I did not understand what u mean by that.

Comment: Just like you said but showing only one of idWerknemer. Thats what im trying to accomplish but with the distinct i cant make it work somehow

Comment: if you are not bother about the idWerknemer value then u can use distinct or group by. But to my opinion it does not make sense just by not getting all idWerknemer values.

Comment: I've edited the question hope it makes sense now;) The idWerknemer is not relevant in this question.

Comment: ok added the answer check if this helps !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use distinct to do so as

```
SELECT distinct `evenementontvanger`.`idEvent`,`evenement`.`title`
FROM
    `evenement`
        JOIN
    `evenementontvanger` ON `evenementontvanger`.`idEvent` = `evenement`.`id`
WHERE
    `idEvent` = `evenement`.`id`;
```

How ever the above will not bother about `idWerknemer` and if you want to display them as group use Group_concat as

```
SELECT `evenementontvanger`.`idEvent`,
`evenement`.`title`,
group_concat(`evenementontvanger`.`idWerknemer`) as `idWerknemer`
FROM
    `evenement`
        JOIN
    `evenementontvanger` ON `evenementontvanger`.`idEvent` = `evenement`.`id`
WHERE
    `idEvent` = `evenement`.`id`

Group By  `evenementontvanger`.`idEvent`
```

Check the demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/290b4/13

Comment: It works in fiddle but somehow when i put it in my sql query i dont get anything:(

Answer (score 1):

Use `SELECT DISTINCT` on your query to eliminate duplicates :

> The ALL and DISTINCT options specify whether duplicate rows should be
>   returned. ALL (the default) specifies that all matching rows should be
>   returned, including duplicates. DISTINCT specifies removal of
>   duplicate rows from the result set. It is an error to specify both
>   options. DISTINCTROW is a synonym for DISTINCT.

[From MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Do i need to do it like this?  $requete = "  SELECT DISTINCT FROM `evenement` JOIN `evenementontvanger` ON `evenementontvanger`.`idEvent` = `evenement`.`id` WHERE `idEvent`=`evenement`.`id`";

Answer (score -1):

use either `top 1`

OR

```
select distinct
```